# Long polynomial division

Tags: diagrams

I'd like to write long division of multivariate polynomials like this

[image]

Any ideas??

Comment: With Ti*k*Z, it is not difficult. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JouleV Well , I don't know how to start, TikZ is some package?

Comment: @marmot  I don't expect from anyone to make want I posted. This is to explain what I'd like to make. I am asking for the way that this can be made (i.e. how could I make the shape of the division?)

Comment: You could start with e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{array}{@{}r@{\,}c@{\,}l|l}
 f_1(x,y,z)&=&x^3yz^6+1 & g(x,y,z)=\dots\\
 \cline{4-4}
 f_1(x,y,z)&=&x^3yz^6+1 & \\
 & & &  g(x,y,z)=\dots\\
 \cline{4-4}
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}` but please understand that no one is keen on punching in these polynomials.

Comment: @marmot I think I got it! thank you! (as I said I don't expect to punch in these specific polynomials)

Comment: Just to be clear: I did not downvote your question but my comment may explain why someone downvoted your question.

Comment: @marmot I think I made it clear that the image I posted is not what I want from someone to make. (I don't mind downvotes) Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `alignat*` should be enough for this layout:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools, bm}

\begin{document}

 \begin{alignat*}{2}
  f_1(x,y,z)&=x^3yz^5+1 &\enspace \smash{\rule[-13em]{0.5pt}{14em}}& \enspace g(x,y,z)=3x^5y^2z - x y^3z + 7yz + 18 \\
  \cline{4-4}
   f_2(x,y,z)&=yz+1 \\[-1.5ex]
    & & & \enspace g(x,y,z)-3x^5yf_2(x, y, z) \\[-2ex]
   \cline{4-4}
 & & & \enspace =3x^5y^2z - x y^3z + 7yz + 18 -3x^5y(yz+1) \\
 \pi_1(x, y, z) & \\[-1.5ex]
  & & & \enspace =3x^5y - x y^3z + 7yz + 18 \\[-2ex]
   \cline{4-4}
 \pi_2(x, y, z) & =3x^5y \\[-1.5ex]
  & & & \enspace - x y^3z + 7yz + 18 \\[-1.5ex]
v(x, y, z) & = \color{red}{\bm{-3x^5y}}
  \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]